# How to post data from NetSuite to other webservice

Tags: netsuite

I have data in the NetSuite. We have provided button in NetSuite. I want to perform HTML Form Post operation on this button click, so that web end point accepts that data and presents on UI.

On button click, we want to simulate HTML Form submission.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: You’ve got to put on a little more work. At least get to the point where you can ask your question in Netsuite terms

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery 11.1 loaded by NetSuite on every page. You can create an inline HTML field with your Javascript/jQuery code.

Just bind a function to the `click` event of the button. In that function you can use `.ajax` to perform an HTTP POST or `.post` to make a form submission to the server.
Don't forget to set `e.preventDefault` at the beginning of your function.